# What is the equivalent of ITopicClient of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in the latest SDK i.e. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: azureservicebus, azure-servicebus-topics

Our application is using older Service Bus SDK i.e. **Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus**. Now we want to move to the latest SDK i.e **Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus**.

But i am not able to find the equivalent of **ITopicClient** of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in the latest SDK i.e. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Basically i want to replace this line of code from older SDK to latest SDK.

```
 private async Task<bool> PublishMessageAsync( IList<IOurApplicationTopicClient> topicClients, 
                                          string topicName)
    {
       // some code 

       ITopicClient primaryTopicClient = topicClients.First(x => 
       x.ServiceBusType.Equals(ServiceBusType.Primary)
       && x.TopicName.Trim().Equals(topicName));

      //some code 
}
```

and the interface IOurApplicationTopicClient is as below.

```
public interface IOurApplicationTopicClient: ITopicClient
{
    ServiceBusType ServiceBusType { get; set; }
    ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder ServiceBusConnectionStringBuilder { get; set; }
}
```

Also i am not sure if there is any propere documentation for smooter migration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [ServiceBusSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebussender?) type is the equivalent; it has the ability to send to either a queue or topic, depending on the `queueOrTopicName` passed when creating it.  The sender is created via the `ServiceBusClient`, using its [CreateSender](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.createsender) method.

The same concept applies for receiving messages, where the [ServiceBusReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusreceiver) has responsibility for reading from both queues and subscriptions, depending on how it is created.  The receiver is also created via the `ServiceBusClient`, using its [CreateReceiver](https://learn.microsoft.com/api/azure.messaging.servicebus.servicebusclient.createreceiver) method.

You may find the [Migration Guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md) helpful for moving to `Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus` from `Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus`.