# Facing issues while migrating my nuget package from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions, azureservicebus, servicebus

Hi All, i was trying to migrate nuget package from Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus to Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus. In my project we have used interfaces like IMessageService, ISenderClient and ITopicClient but couldnt find the related interfaces in the updated package. Can anyone let me know what can we use in its replacement. Thanks for the help

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the equivalent of ITopicClient of Microsoft.Azure.ServiceBus in the latest SDK i.e. Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69072932/what-is-the-equivalent-of-itopicclient-of-microsoft-azure-servicebus-in-the-late)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer. Do you mean that all interfaces have been removed and we need to use the related classes?

Comment: Refer to [Migration guide](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-net/blob/main/sdk/servicebus/Azure.Messaging.ServiceBus/MigrationGuide.md)